# i need to move a subset's subheader from one cell place its value adjacent to its respective row

Tags: vba, excel

The request sounded simple enough: "I need you to create some code that would create a column, move the property codes to the same row as the units...". I thought "Cool, I'll send the code via email - after I make this project my bitch...". That was two days ago...

Below is a snippet of the report and the finished output. Thanks in advance for your help. Needless to say, this project was humbling. Oh yeah, I noticed the last MultiFamily unit "112" s/b "112". I'll correct that.

Report before/after

[image]

The actual report is over 5K records but the format is the same. Below is the actual data:

```
Fig 1.
           (A)                                  |   (B)
(01)  Property                                  | Tenant  
(02)  Unit                                      | Code
(03)  118 - MultiFamily Facility 1              |
(04)         0118                               | t0103001
(05)         0121                               | t0077028
(06)         0124                               | t0099589
(07)         Total 118 - MultiFamily Facility 1 |
(08)  119 - MultiFamily Facility 2              |
(09)         001                                | t0103128
(10)         002                                | t0101985
(11)         003                                | t0102938
(12)         Total 119 - MultiFamily Facility 2 |
(13)  121 - MultiFamily Facility 3              |
(14)         001                                | t0099507
(15)         002                                | t0101773
(16)         003                                | t0103123
(17)         004                                | t0099821
(18)         005                                | t0077281
(19)         Total 121- MultiFamily Facility 3  |  


fig.2

      (A)      |    (B)    |  (C)
(01)  Property |    Unit   |  Tenant Code
(02)  118      |    0118   |   t0103001
(03)  118      |    0121   |   t0077028
(04)  118      |    0124   |   t0099589
(05)           |     Total 118 - MultiFamily Facility 1 
(06)  119      |    001    |   t0103128
(07)  119      |    002    |   t0101985
(08)  119      |    003    |   t0102938
(09)           |     Total 119 - MultiFamily Facility 2 
(10)  121      |    001    |   t0099507
(11)  121      |    002    |   t0101773
(12)  121      |    003    |   t0103123
(13)  121      |    004    |   t0099821
(14)  121      |    005    |   t0077281
(15)           |     Total 121 - MultiFamily Facility 3
```

Comment: I posted an image of original output and the reformatted report.

Comment: Please also post your code and what isn't working for you.

Comment: @OldUgly they never have code XD

Comment: second time I have seen this, what does the s/b in the question refer to?

Comment: @ForwardEd - I am going to guess it's dyslexia: 112 should be 121. Don't know what s/b means, however. (should be?)

Comment: Yeah, correct, it should be (s/b) "121". I was in a rush leaving work.

Comment: Questions:  1)  Do the unit numbers have leading spaces or are the cells formatted to indent.  2) Does the character - ever show up in the cell with a unit number?

Comment: @tdub4034 - have you developed any code that we can help you with? Or are you hoping that SO to gift a solution to you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are better ways to code the following but this will do what you require based on the information you supplied.  It will not do the formatting.  You can record a separate macro for that yourself, or just format manually.

If you are doing this operation multiple times, there are ways of automating last row, header row, and column numbers.  I have essentially hard coded them, but you could also tweak this to work with selected range, but I was not that bored, nor are my skills that advanced.

```
Option Explicit

Sub MakeReport()
Dim HeaderRow, FirstRow, LastRow, sPropertyCol, sTenantCol, dPropertyCol, dUnitCol, dTenantCol, CounterX, CounterY As Long
Dim wsSource, wsDest As Worksheet
Dim PropertyNumber As String

'This chunk of code defines where the source information is and
'were destination information goes in terms of column and row numbers

HeaderRow = 2
FirstRow = 3
LastRow = 19

sPropertyCol = 1
sTenantCol = 2

dPropertyCol = 1
dUnitCol = 2
dTenantCol = 3

'This is the first row of Data on the destination sheet
CounterY = 2

'rename the sheets as required to suit your sheet names
Set wsSource = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set wsDest = Worksheets("Sheet2")

'Taking care of the rearranged header inofrmation
wsDest.Range("A1") = wsSource.Range("A1")
wsDest.Range("B1") = wsSource.Range("A2")
wsDest.Range("C1") = wsSource.Range("B1") & " " & wsSource.Range("B2")

'Loop through data check if its a total row then
'Check if its a property row
'otherwise treat it as a unit row
'Does not eliminate blank lines, just repeats them

For CounterX = FirstRow To LastRow
    If InStr(wsSource.Cells(CounterX, sPropertyCol).Value, "Total") = 0 Then
        If InStr(wsSource.Cells(CounterX, sPropertyCol).Value, "-") <> 0 Then
           PropertyNumber = Left(wsSource.Cells(CounterX, sPropertyCol).Value, InStr(wsSource.Cells(CounterX, sPropertyCol).Value, "-") - 2)
        Else
           wsDest.Cells(CounterY, dPropertyCol).Value = PropertyNumber
           wsDest.Cells(CounterY, dUnitCol).Value = wsSource.Cells(CounterX, sPropertyCol).Value
           wsDest.Cells(CounterY, dTenantCol).Value = wsSource.Cells(CounterX, sTenantCol).Value
           'increase the row you are going to write to next
           CounterY = CounterY + 1
        End If
    Else
        wsDest.Cells(CounterY, dUnitCol).Value = wsSource.Cells(CounterX, sPropertyCol).Value
        'increase the row you are going to write to next
        CounterY = CounterY + 1
    End If
Next CounterX

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Same answer, some different techniques ...

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()
Dim srcSht As Worksheet, tarSht As Worksheet
Dim srcRng As Range, tarRange As Range
Dim myCell As Range, myStr As String, ZeroStr As String
Dim myFacility As Long, nZeros As Long
Dim srcFirstRow As Long, srcLastRow As Long, tarLastRow As Long
Dim iLoop As Long, jLoop As Long, iCount As Long


' initialize
    Set srcSht = Worksheets("Sheet1") '<~~ pick the sheet names you need
    Set tarSht = Worksheets("Sheet2")

    srcFirstRow = 3
    srcLastRow = srcSht.Range("A" & srcSht.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set srcRng = srcSht.Range(srcSht.Cells(1, 1), srcSht.Cells(srcLastRow, 3))

    myFacility = -1
    iCount = 1
' prepare the target sheet
    tarLastRow = tarSht.Range("B" & tarSht.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    tarSht.Range(tarSht.Cells(1, 1), tarSht.Cells(tarLastRow, 3)).Delete (xlUp)
    tarSht.Range("A1").Value = "Property"
    tarSht.Range("B1").Value = "Unit"
    tarSht.Range("C1").Value = "Tenant Code"
' you may want to add some formatting of the target sheet at this point


    For iLoop = srcFirstRow To srcLastRow
        myStr = ""
        If InStr(srcRng.Range("A" & iLoop).Value, "-") Then
' find the facility heading, the number goes in myFacility
            myStr = Trim(Split(srcRng.Range("A" & iLoop), "-")(0))
            myFacility = -1
            On Error Resume Next
                If Len(myStr) > 0 Then myFacility = CLng(myStr)
            On Error GoTo 0
            If myFacility = -1 Then
                iCount = iCount + 1
                tarSht.Cells(iCount, 2).Value = srcRng.Cells(iLoop, 1).Value
            End If
        Else
' put values in target sheet
            iCount = iCount + 1
            tarSht.Cells(iCount, 1).Value = myFacility
            tarSht.Cells(iCount, 2).Value = srcRng.Range("A" & iLoop).Value
            nZeros = Len(Trim(srcRng.Range("A" & iLoop).Value))
            ZeroStr = ""
            For jLoop = 1 To nZeros
                ZeroStr = ZeroStr & "0"
            Next jLoop
            tarSht.Range("B" & iCount).NumberFormat = ZeroStr '<~~ set this as needed
            tarSht.Cells(iCount, 3).Value = srcRng.Range("B" & iLoop).Value
        End If

    Next iLoop
End Sub
```

Comment: interesting tweaks.  Questions:  1)  Is the on error resume next there to catch the total row since both the total row and the first property row both have "-" in them?  2)  Do this method maintain leading zeros or does it convert the string to numbers..or is that what the nZeros is for?

Comment: 1) Yes. 2)It converts to number so the zeros get lost. So I count the zeros (nZeros) and format the cell to display them. ZeroStr ends up being "0000" or "000". I think there's a more efficient way to do this, but haven't looked it up yet.

Comment: Jeeped had a nice way of doing it if you were keeping it a s a string using excel formulas.  No reason it would not work here.  Just concatenate a huge string of just "000000000" to the left side, then take a RIGHT ( big string, number of characters to display)